# Instance of class `object`

Tags: python

I wish to make an instance of built-in class `object`, and use it as container for some variables (like `struct` in C++):

```
Python 3.2 (r32:88445, Mar 25 2011, 19:56:22) 
>>> a=object()
>>> a.f=2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'object' object has no attribute 'f'
```

Is there a way to accomplish this easier than doing:

```
>>> class struct():
...     '''Container'''
... 
>>> a=struct()
>>> a.f=2
>>> a.f
2
>>>
```

**UPDATE:**

- i need a container to hold some variables, but i don't want to use
  dict - to be able to write `a.f = 2` instead of `a['f'] = 2`
- > using a derived class saves you from typing the quotes
- also, sometimes autocomplete works

Comment: why exactly do you want to do this?

Comment: i need a container to hold some variables, but i don't want to use dict - to be able to write `a.f = 2` instead of `a['f'] = 2`

Comment: Why don't you want to write `a['f'] = 2` for just the sugar of writing `a.f = 2` it seems a bit stupid.

Comment: I guess there is no other way but to define a custom class like you have done if you don't want to use dict. *Why don't you want to write 2 lines in defining a custom class yourself?* You can keep that in some other module if you don't want to mix it with your existing code.

Comment: yes, that's what i do. just wondered why i can't add attributes to `object()` and if there is another way.

Comment: Perhaps because `__slots__` is defined for `object` class which prevents you from adding more attributes to it. You don't define `__slots__` for your custom class and hence you are able to assign attributes to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recognize the sentiment against dicts, and I therefore often use either NamedTuples or classes.  Nice short hand is provided by `Bunch` in the Python [Cookbook](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52308-the-simple-but-handy-collector-of-a-bunch-of-named/), allowing you to do declaration and assignment in one:

```
point = Bunch(x=x, y=y, squared=y*y)
point.x
```

The printed Cookbook (2ed) has an extensive discussion on this.

IMHO, the reason why object has no slots and no dict is readability:  If you use an (anonymous) object to store coordinates first and then another object to store client data, you may get confused.  Two class definitions makes it clear which one is which.  Bunches don't.

Answer (score 4):

No, you have to subclass `object` to get a mutable object. Make sure to do so explicitly in python 2.x:

```
class Struct(object):
    pass
```

Probably using a built-in container is better though, if only because it's clear from syntax exactly what it is.

The reason instances of `object` can't be assigned to is that they don't have either a `__dict__` or a `__slots__` attribute, the two places where instance data can be stored.

```
>>> dir(object())
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', 
 '__hash__', '__init__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', 
 '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__']
```

Basically this is equivalent to declaring `__slots__ = []`.

If you know all the fields you want your `Struct` to have, *you* could use `slots` to make a mutable `namedtuple`-like data structure:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     __slots__ = ['a', 'b', 'c']
... 
>>> f = Foo()
>>> f.a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: a
>>> f.a = 5
>>> f.a
5
```

But you can only assign values to attribute names listed in `__slots__`:

```
>>> f.d = 5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Foo' object has no attribute 'd'
```

Comment: Did I mention if I ever have to maintain such code I'll hunt down the writer and take horrible revenge? Not sure if you're not guilty of aiding and abetting ;)

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Its called a dict.

```
structything = {}
structything['f'] = 2
print structything['f']
print structything.get('f')
```

Id link you to the documents but they are down atm.

Comment: even though using a dict is the pythonic way, using a derived class saves you from typing the quotes...

Comment: I wonder what the O(n) complexity is, the cost in memory of the instance, Im guessing same as dict right?